# glm function in R uses incorrect coefficient?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have the test scores of two groups, a and b.

```
    test.a=c(1.12, 1, 2, 1.4, 2)
    test.b=c(2, 1, 1.5, 1.7, 1)
```

If the person scores over 1.1, I want to label him/her as positive.

```
    test.a=ifelse(test.a>1.1,'positive','negative')
    test.b=ifelse(test.b>1.1,'positive', 'negative')
    test.ab=c(test.a, test.b)
```

The status is a binary response variable that indicates whether the person has the disease or not (0 = no diseae, 1=disease)

```
   status=c(rep(0,2), rep(1,3))
   status=as.factor(status)
   test.ab=as.factor(test.ab)
   test.data=data.frame(status, test.ab)
   test.fit=glm(status~test.ab, data=test.data, family="binomial")
   summary(test.fit)
```

The summary function returns

```
   Call:
   glm(formula = status ~ test.ab, family = "binomial", data = test.data)

   Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
   -1.58   -0.90    0.82    0.82    1.48  

   Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
   (Intercept)       -0.693      1.225   -0.57     0.57
   test.abpositive    1.609      1.483    1.09     0.28
```

I don't understand why is positive appended to test.ab? Shouldn't the coefficient just be test.ab as I have specified in the data.frame and in the glm() command?

Comment: `test.ab` is a categorical variable with two categories. `test.abpositive` gives you the difference being categorised as 'positive' has on the log odds, compared to the baseline which in this case is chosen to be `test.abnegative`.

Comment: you can explicitly code it as 0 and 1 if you don't want this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
test.a=c(1.12, 1, 2, 1.4, 2)
test.b=c(2, 1, 1.5, 1.7, 1)
test.a=ifelse(test.a>1.1,1,0)
test.b=ifelse(test.b>1.1,1,0)


test.ab=c(test.a, test.b)


status=c(rep(0,2), rep(1,3))
status=as.factor(status)
test.data=data.frame(status, test.ab)
test.fit=glm(status~test.ab, data=test.data, family="binomial")
summary(test.fit)
```